# My poll results for my coloured bars don't work

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

I am trying to make a poll with two pink bars to show the percentages of the results. I made my percentage bars images, although when I used the poll, they stay the same size and don't get any smaller/bigger according to their %. How should I change the code so that the % bars change their lengths?

[image: Here is the image]

HMTL code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function getVote(int) {
  var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("poll").innerHTML=this.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","poll_vote.php?vote="+int,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="poll">
<h3>Do you like PHP and AJAX so far?</h3>
<form>
Yes: <input type="radio" name="vote" value="0" onclick="getVote(this.value)"><br>
No: <input type="radio" name="vote" value="1" onclick="getVote(this.value)">
</form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP file:

```
<?php
$vote = $_REQUEST['vote'];

//get content of textfile
$filename = "poll_result.txt";
$content = file($filename);

//put content in array
$array = explode("||", $content[0]);
$yes = $array[0];
$no = $array[1];

if ($vote == 0) {
  $yes = $yes + 1;
}
if ($vote == 1) {
  $no = $no + 1;
}

//insert votes to txt file
$insertvote = $yes."||".$no;
$fp = fopen($filename,"w");
fputs($fp,$insertvote);
fclose($fp);
?>

<h2>Result:</h2>
<table>
<tr>
<td>Yes:</td>
<td><img src="images/poll.png"
width='<?php echo(100*round($yes/($no+$yes),2)); ?>'
height='20'>
<?php echo(100*round($yes/($no+$yes),2)); ?>%
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>No:</td>
<td><img src="images/poll.png"
width='<?php echo(100*round($no/($no+$yes),2)); ?>'
height='20'>
<?php echo(100*round($no/($no+$yes),2)); ?>%
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You are using an image. How you expect an image to resize according to the percentage? Use CSS to do this. Try this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/progress Also there are options in CSS Frameworks like Bootstrap. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/progress/

Comment: Sorry, how could I do that with CSS? Do you think I could use a gif?

Comment: No. Refer Above Links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use image for indicating progress. Use `<progress>` or other HTML element with CSS.

I have changed your `poll_vote.php` file to use `<progress>` element.

```php
<?php
$vote = $_REQUEST['vote'];

//get content of textfile
$filename = "poll_result.txt";
$content = file($filename);

//put content in array
$array = explode("||", $content[0]);
$yes = $array[0];
$no = $array[1];

if ($vote == 0) {
  $yes = $yes + 1;
}
if ($vote == 1) {
  $no = $no + 1;
}

//insert votes to txt file
$insertvote = $yes."||".$no;
$fp = fopen($filename,"w");
fputs($fp,$insertvote);
fclose($fp);

$yesProgress = 100*round($yes/($no+$yes),2);
$noProgress = 100*round($no/($no+$yes),2);
?>

<h2>Result:</h2>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Yes:</td>

        <td>
        <progress id="file" max="100" value="<?= $yesProgress ?>">
            <?= $yesProgress ?>
        </progress>
        <?= $yesProgress ?>%
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>No:</td>
        <td>
        <progress id="file" max="100" value="<?= $noProgress ?>">
            <?= $noProgress ?>
        </progress>
        <?= $noProgress ?>%
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Refer below Links:

[HTML Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/progress)

[Bootstrap 4 Progress Bars](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/progress/)

Comment: wow thanks! That did work. Sorry again, how could I add a percentage label which increases as the % increases?